# The skill must close when using the exist command without returning an error response - Alexa skill Certification Issue

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm getting this error when submitting for alexa skill certification:

**"The skill must close when using the exist command without returning an error response."**

> The skill does not close the session or respond appropriately when
>   users say "exit". Instead, the skill returns an error response. Please
>   make sure the skill does not return errors when receiving
>   SessionEndedRequests sent by Alexa.

Already checked the skill for any issues, and there are no errors.
I tried command "Exit", and found an error like "

> There was a problem with the requested skill's response

Can you please help me to fix this issue. I already have AMAZON.StopIntent which manage the stop request. All sessions are closed with, .withShouldEndSession(true) but still the issue is there for certification. I tried to add "exit" utterance in the AMAZON.StopIntent and still not solved my problem. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Alexa developer must include Request Handler as below,

- HelpIntentHandler ()
- CancelAndStopIntentHandler ()
- SessionEndedRequestHandler ()

And also a Error Handler like,

```
exports.handler = skillBuilder
  .withSkillId("amzn1.ask.skill.1")
  .addRequestHandlers(
    HelloWorldIntentHandler,
    LaunchRequestHandler,
    HelpIntentHandler,
    CancelAndStopIntentHandler,
    SessionEndedRequestHandler,
  )
  .addErrorHandlers(ErrorHandler)
  .lambda();
```

You can add these like this way,

```
 const HelpIntentHandler = {
      canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
          && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.HelpIntent';
      },
      handle(handlerInput) {
        const speechText = 'Your skill help content will be here';

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
          .speak(speechText)
          .reprompt(speechText)
          .getResponse();
      },
    };

    const CancelAndStopIntentHandler = {
      canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
          && (handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.CancelIntent'
            || handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.StopIntent');
      },
      handle(handlerInput) {
        const speechText = 'Goodbye!';

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
          .speak(speechText)
          .getResponse();
      },
    };


    const SessionEndedRequestHandler = {
      canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'SessionEndedRequest';
      },
      handle(handlerInput) {
        console.log(`Session ended with reason: ${handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.reason}`);

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder.getResponse();
      },
    };

    const ErrorHandler = {
      canHandle() {
        return true;
      },
      handle(handlerInput, error) {
        console.log(`Error handled: ${error.message}`);

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
          .speak('Sorry, I can\'t understand the command. Please say again.')
          .getResponse();
      },
    };
```

Also you can more details about [voice interaction and User experience Testing](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/voice-interface-and-user-experience-testing-for-a-custom-skill.html) 
and can verify your skill manually for the certification.